# capacitor ground or not?

Tags: capacitor, ground, automotive

I recently started developing an interest for electronics (doing mods for my car, Delayed lights etc...) so I decided to sign up here.

I have some questions about capacitors (which are very new to me).

My question is since they have got +/- sides, do I need to ground them or does this work on hot side only like the image, say the bulb in the image is car park lights. As far as I know, this should take about 1.5 sec to reach 12V.

[image: Illustration Image]

Comment: not all capacitors have polarity (+-) ... for those that do, the `+` terminal has to remain at a higher voltage than the `-` terminal ... for example, if you connect the `+` to the +12V, and the `-` to +6V, then you would be ok

Comment: So are you saying whats on the image will work as it should?

Comment: We have no idea how it *should* work...

Comment: 12.8v +- your answer is confusing maybe i asked in a bad way. the red /hot line is powered by a 12v battery witch hopefully will power the bulb. My initial question do i need to ground the capacitor in any way or can it stay only on the red/hot line like the image?

Comment: if you connect a polarized capacitor backwards and it blows up, it is really `working as it should`, because that is what happens when you reverse polarity

Comment: Shouldn't it get a delay cause of the resistor before capacitor? (Led wont turn on unless 12v) but to clarify the wiring is correct right?

Comment: ok sorry didnt know

Comment: you have not said what you want the circuit to do, so there is no way to tell if it is correct

Comment: Welcome to the site, Brian :-) What you have drawn will not damage the capacitor because of bad polarity, you have the '+' terminal going to the higher voltage. Can you edit your question to add some details. The capacitor voltage rating is very important and its type would be very useful. Also, can you explain briefly what you want the circuit to do. The better the quality of your question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: Thanks. i do apologize with the quality of the question its kind of 2 in 1. What my goal is: make light turn on after a time delay. from the answer this wont work. but i belive it will since 1k resistor will make the capacitor use about 1.5 sec to reach 12v wich my bulb needs before it even will turn on. but my main question was is this wiring correct. since capacitors have +/-.

Answer (score 6):

What you have is technically correct. The voltage on the positive terminals of polarized caps must always be greater than the negative terminal. What voltage the negative terminal is at is not significant.

What it functionally does here may not be what you intend.

As shown, the LED will light when you apply power then dim out shortly after as the capacitor charges up. Subsequently it may never light again, or not for the very long time it takes for the capacitor to leak it's charge.

Further, if your LED is actually the car lights, the 1K resistor will not provide enough current to light them.

edit: here is a rough diagram of what you get once the capacitor charges up.  the voltage on both sides of the LED will be the close to the same, so no light

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyS2YW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

---

For something like you are describing you would need something like this..

(Ignore the two switches.. they are just for testing in the schematic editor)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYRMGa.png)</sup>

When you switch on the circuit C1 charges up through R1. When the voltage reaches the threshold voltage of the N_MOSFET the latter turns on which switches on the P-MOSFET turning on your lights. Delay time is set by the R1, C1 combination and also depends on the gate threshold of the N-MOSFET. You want the latter to be closer to 6V than 1V.

Making R1 a 1 Meg pot will allow you to adjust the delay.

When you open the switch, the capacitor will discharge, initially through the light till M2 turns off, then though the diode D1 and the smaller resistor R3.

R2 simply biases M1 off.

If you want to build this, you need to use MOSFETS that are designed to handle automobile transient voltages.

Here is  simpler version that only uses a P-MOSFET. It works sort of the same way as the previous one but the charge circuit is reversed. The switching edge with a single transistor is much slower though and may cause some flickering in the lights as they turn on.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fo7uP9.png)</sup>

Comment: So this is a correct usage of capacitor and wont short circuit the system/battery?
Wouldn't the resistor just slow down the capacitor charging time or have i misunderstood?

Comment: @Brian correct. If you need a delay before turn on you need something different.

Comment: I understand i do appreciate the help!

Comment: @Trevor_G, i took liberty to add a diagram to your answer, i hope it's ok.

Comment: @Brian see addition.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead.
Note 1: This is an extremely simplistic and poorly controlled design, but it's a quick way of achieving your goal.

Note 2:  If what you have labelled as an LED is actually an LED, you will need a resistor in series with it or else it will draw too much current and burn out.  If it's a lamp for a car, it most likely does NOT require a resistor, which is why i've shown it without one here.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmmhlC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The reason your designed circuit won't work as you want is because once a capacitor is charged, current no longer passes through it.  And your lamp needs current to emit light.  Here's a trick - to find out what a circuit does after a long time, you can just delete the capacitors from the circuit.  In your case, that means the lamp is no longer connected to anything, so of course it will be off.

Regarding your original question about capacitors:
"Ground" is an arbitrarily selected reference point that means 0V.  ANY point in a circuit could be declared as the 0V "ground" point without affecting how it works.  In general, absolute voltages never mean anything - all that matters is the voltage DIFFERENCE between the two terminals of a device.

So for capacitors, if a capacitor is polarized (has a + and - node), then all you need is to make sure that the voltage at the + node is greater than or equal to the voltage at the - node.  You do NOT have to connect the - node to ground.

Comment: YOu still need a decent discharge path on that.

Comment: Also low side switching on cars is problematic since the chassis is the return wire.

Comment: Yes and yes, but the OP's application is pretty ambiguously defined so I wanted to get the concept across without making things too complicated.  Judging from the initial diagram, we're waaay back at EE101 in this question :)

Comment: Or grade 11.. :D

Answer (score 0):

You have a high-pass pulser. Fast rise and predictable delay. Is that what you need, or are you just playing to learn?

[image]

This circuit used 1nanoFarad and 160 ohms.